# Vector size in watch expressions is not true

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I am new to C++ and Visual Studio and I have a little issue with the watch expression window on visual studio 2015. The Result of the code below is : 16.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TopSecretLib.h";

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> v = SomeFunction1362();
    std::cout << v.size();
    return 0;
}
```

But when I insert into the  watch expression window the value `v` the result is :
[image: debug problem]

**UPDATE:**
I added this picture to clarify my problem
[image]

Comment: On what line are you when you took that image.  Generally you have to step to the next line to see the effects of the previous line.  For example When you execute the line `std::cout << v.size();` it should show `v`'s correct size in the watch window.

Comment: my breakpoint is on `return 0` line

Comment: You're going to need to remove `SomeFunction1362()` from the question. What if the problem is in there? Present your [MCVE].

Comment: Perhaps there's undefined behaviour in `SomeFunction1362` which causes your program to do random things. And are you sure the output is 16 and not 0?

Comment: If you try `vector<unsigned char> v = { 0,1,2,3,4 }; cout << v.size() << endl`; what is the output then?

Comment: What optimization level (/O) are you using?

Comment: @Stephan Lechner The ouput from code is same in debugger and console - 5. So the problem is with the SomeFunction1326 I dont have the source code of this function, what can be the problem in this function?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Disabled (/Od)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition The problem is in the function , see my comment to stephan. What can be the problem in the function? ( I dont have the source code of the function)

Comment: @RonBadur: It could be almost anything. Who has the source code? You're going to need to talk to them about this problem.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Ok Thanks for your help, I will close the question to prevent more spam

Comment: @RonBadur: Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be visualization is left for customization by visual studio.

`Natvis views` allows us to customize the display view for types in watch window.

In the below link search for "**Natvis views**".

You will see a C++ example for `std::vector`.

There you can see how the size is displayed in watch window.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx

The above link also explains how to create a ".natvis" file and add to your debug build (look for "Adding .natvis files to your projects")

Comment: The viewer for `std::vector` comes built in to Visual Studio, so I don't know what you're trying to say here. Unless you think the built-in one was overridden somehow? I've certainly never seen it give the wrong size.

Comment: @Mark Ransom, But I did not get it with "Microsoft visual studio professional 2015". I see in watch window {size=0} even though the vector has size.... Could you please tell me which version of VS you are using? Just want to know more on this issue.. Thanks.

Comment: I've got 2013. It seems odd that they would regress like that, but not totally impossible.

Comment: I am also surprised seeing that....